# Use a DOMAIN in multiple schemas

Tags: postgresql, schema, domain

The PostgreSQL [CREATE DOMAIN](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createdomain.html) command appears to create the domain at the schema level. Is there a best approach I should be aware of that would allow me to  reuse domains across the multiple schemas that comprise my database?

Comment: Are you looking for `your_schema.your_domain`?

Comment: @dezso yeah I guess I can do that too but than I would have to decide in which particular schema to declare the domains that are used by more or less all other schemas and why to put the domain definitions in schema 'a' versus schema 'b'. Maybe I'll just create a schema solely for domain definitions.

Comment: Basically you have to decide the same for every object.  When you don't specify the schema, the system will call `search_path` to help and pick the first schema from there (more or less).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store them in the `public` schema if you're using them in more than one schema. That's what it's there for.

Typically, I don't. If you have a domain in more than one schema that usually indicates to me that either,

- the type should be packaged as an extension and in it's own schema.
- your two schemas should merge.

But there is nothing wrong with using the public schema.